# Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed space. If $Y$ is a nonzero normed space,then there is some $F:X\to Y$ which is linear but not closed

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional normed space. If $Y$ is a nonzero normed space,then there is some $F:X\to Y$ which is linear but not closed.

I know that every infinite dimensional normed space has a discontinous linear functional. But how to find a linear functional which is linear but not closed.

Comment: There is a big problem here with the definitions. In FA  a linear map is closed if its graph is closed. This is different from the notion of  a closed map in topology.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a dis-continuous linear functional then there is a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $f(x_n) \to \infty$. [See details below].  Let $y_n=\frac {x_n} {f(x_n)}$. Then $y_n \to 0$ and $f(y_n)=1$ for all $n$. So $(y_n,f(y_n))$ is  a sequence in the graph of $f$ which converges to $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)$ is not in the graph of $f$. Hence, $f$ is not  a closed linear map (in the FA sense).

[ There exist $u_n$ with $ u_n \to 0$ such that  $f(u_n)$ does not tend to $0$. There is a subsequence $(w_n)$ of $(u_n)$ and $r>0$ such that $f(w_n) \geq r$ for all $n$. [You may have to replace $u_n$ by $c_nu_n$ with $|c_n|=1$ if necessary). Take $x_n=\frac {w_n} {\sqrt {\|w_n\|}}$].

$f$ is not closed in the topological sense either!

We can modify above argument to get $y_n\to 0$ but $f(y_n)=1-\frac 1 n$. In that case $\{0,y_1,y_2,..\}$ is a clsoed set whose image is not closed (since $1$ is  a limit point  which is not in the image.